# How can I (if it is even possible) use the Pentaho Carte logging_string field to obtain a human readable log

Tags: pentaho

I have installed Pentaho Carte in a host so i can run ETL jobs making an HTTP request to the Carte server. The thing is once a job has finished the log of this job may be incomplete because the log buffer is small. In this cases i'm losing a great part of the desired log. Researching i have seen there is a field called logging_string in the XML that is returned from the job status. Now this field looks like it may store the complete log of the Job Execution, but it seems to be encrypted or in a non-readable format. Is there a way i can decrypt/format this "logging_string" so it is human readable?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched in the pentaho-kettle code hosted on Github and found this class https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/www/SlaveServerJobStatus.java , the class explains that the logging_string is a CDATA block with a Base64 encoded GZIP compressed stream of data. It also imports another class called org.pentaho.di.cluster.HttpUtil that provides a method to decode the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually view the contents using command line (as opposed to automated code to do it), you can try the following.

Save the CDATA portion of the string to a text file. Note that this is the part inside of the double square brackets. Do not include the double square brackets.

Let's say you save the content to a text file named `log-string.txt`.

Then you can issue the following commands in series of pipes. First command prints the file to stdout. This is then passed to the `base64` command with the `-d` option to decode it. This is then piped to the gunzip command.

`cat log-string.txt | base64 -d | gunzip`

The output from this sequence of pipes will be the contents of the log file in plain text.